# WPF: filtering ItemCollection of a ComboBox also filters other ComboBoxes bound to the same ItemsSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

Given a "customer" entity:

```
public class CustomerEntity: EntityBase
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> ClientsOfCustomer = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public CustomerEntity() 
    {
        // Load ClientsOfCustomer...
    }
}
```

and two or more WPF ComboBoxes that have their `ItemsSourceProperty` bound to the same source (say, an attribute of the above "Customer" entity):

```
var comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
var comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
comboBox1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
    new Binding(itemsSourceProperty) { ElementName = "ClientsOfCustomer" });
comboBox2.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
    new Binding(itemsSourceProperty) { ElementName = "ClientsOfCustomer" });
```

The above is done before we actually have an instance of the underlying object. This happens sometime later in the application:

```
var customer = new CustomerEntity();
parentPageOfComboboxes.DataContext = customer;
```

if we then filter the `ItemCollection` of either `ComboBox`:

```
comboBox1.Items.Filter = i => ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)i).Value.StartsWith("a");
```

this ends up filtering the other `ComboBox` as well.

I understand that this is because `ComboBox` is a `Selector`, which is an `ItemsControl`, and `ItemsControl` invokes `ItemCollection.SetItemsSource` when the `ItemsSource` `DependencyProperty` changes. `ItemCollection` then in turn makes use of `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView( _itemsSource, ModelParent, GetSourceItem)` to grab the default `CollectionView` associated with the given `_itemsSource` from cache. Therefore if you set the Filter on the underlying `ItemCollection` of one `ComboBox`, you are actually setting it on the cached and shared `CollectionView` associated with the `ItemsSource` that the `ComboBox` is bound to. I guess the WPF folks didn't expect anyone to want to do so - unfortunate. But what can I do about it?

I've found two similar questions on SO without any real answer: "[Filtered Combobox ItemsSource binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852769/filtered-combobox-itemssource-binding-issue)" (which seems to be about a custom "FilteredComboBox") and "[Wpf ListBoxes' ItemsSource strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713688/wpf-listboxes-itemssource-strange-behaviour) (which involves listboxes without data binding).

I've also implemented a fairly ugly solution that I will include below as an answer. However, there must be a better way.

UPDATE/CLARIFICATION: I did not express myself clearly in my original question. The answer to this question is trivial in cases where we have access to the actual instance of the entity that we are binding to at the time of data binding. However, I have a complex application that generates forms "on-the-fly" from metadata (which can come from C# Attributes, or from meta-data stored in a database, it doesn't matter). In the other similar questions posed on SO, the actual binding source (the data context) is always available, so simply doing something like `Items = new ListCollectionView(...);` (either in code or in XAML) is possible. But what if the actual `DataContext` is only set somewhere much further down the application lifecycle based on metadata? What solution is there other than something very crude like looping through all generated UI elements and altering the binding source retroactively? I hope this clarification is understandable.

Comment: See: [Multiple ItemsControl on single collection applies filter to all views at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542781/multiple-itemscontrol-on-single-collection-applies-filter-to-all-views-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

**An Ugly Solution**

I created my own `MyComboBox` that inherits from `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox`. In `MyComboBox` I override metadata for the `ItemsSourceProperty` [as described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-override-metadata-for-a-dependency-property) so that whenever the `ItemsSource` changes I actually bind to a new `ListCollectionView`:

```
public partial class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    static MyComboBox()
    {
        ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((IEnumerable)null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl ic = (ItemsControl)d;
        IEnumerable oldValue = (IEnumerable)e.OldValue;
        IEnumerable newValue = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;

        // We get into infinite recursion land without the following condition:
        if (newValue.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<int, string>))
        {
            var cvs = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = ((Dictionary<int, string>)newValue) };
            ic.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that the `if (newValue.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<int, string>))` condition is required, otherwise you get into an infinite recursion loop (`MyComboBox` sets `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` which changes the `ItemsSourceProperty`, which then triggers `ic.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue)` leading back to `MyComboBox.OnItemsSourceChanged` and so on.

Another caveat: simply doing `ic.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(((Dictionary<int, string>)newValue).ToList());` would seem to work except that any changes to the underlying `ObservableCollection` will not update the bound `ComboBox`. So it seems necessary to create a new `CollectionViewSource`, set the `Source` and bind to the view as above. This is also what is recommended in the [official docs for CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netframework-4.8):

> You should not create objects of this class in your code. To create a
>   collection view for a collection that only implements IEnumerable,
>   create a CollectionViewSource object, add your collection to the
>   Source property, and get the collection view from the View property.

**So the above works but it's pretty ugly. Is there really no better way?**

Answer (score 1):

Your observations are correct. Every `ItemsControl` that binds to the same source collection, shares a common default `ICollectionView` of this collection.

The solution is to create dedicated instances of `ICollectionView` for each `ComboBox`. You can define them in XAML using a `CollectionViewSource` like in the example below. If the filter is triggered by a`Button` you can use a command to bind this `Button` to filter predicate defined in your view model, passing the `CollectionViewSource` as `CommandParameter`.

Otherwise define the `ICollectionView` as properties in your view model and bind to them. You can now set the filter predicate directly without using a trigger (command) from the view.

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> Data source { get; set; }

ICommand ApplyFilterCommand => new RelayCommand(FilterCollectionView);

private void FilterCollectionView(object param)
{  
    CollectionView collectionView = (param as CollectionViewSource).View;
    collectionView.Filter = item => item.StartsWith("a");
    collectionView.Refresh();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel />
    <Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="FirstCollectionSource" 
                              Source="{Binding DataSource}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SecondCollectionSource" 
                              Source="{Binding DataSource}" />
    <Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FirstCollectionSource}}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SecondCollectionSource}}" />

        <!-- Filter the second ComboBox -->
        <Button Command="{Binding ApplyFilterCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{StaticResource SecondCollectionSource}" />
    </StackPanel>
<Window>
```

Comment: My apoligies, my original question was not clear enough. I've made some clarifications. So, basically, I don't have access to the actual binding source (the data context) when the ComboBoxes are created, so I cannot just do as you describe above :-(